# Enabling Virtualization in Lenovo G-50 BIOS

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, haxm

I have a Lenovo G-50 laptop and need to enable virtualization in the BIOS for my Android emulator. How should I proceed?

I tried doing it with the Novo key and the F-keys but it is not showing anything. I am a beginner in Flutter development. Please help if you can.

Comment: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/g50-80/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers